# Understanding speed distributions: Average speed, RMS speed from a graph?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, integration

So taking a look at this graph....

![https://i.stack.imgur.com/39SDo.png

I want to express $A$ in terms of $N$ (total # of particles) and $V_0$. So I've found the piecewise function for $f(v)$ and got:

Comment: I believe I've transcribed your equations correctly, you may want to check to verify them.

Comment: Yes, everything you fixed is correct!

Comment: Okay, then you've made a mistake in your 2nd integral, because you shouldn't have any $v$'s, just $V_0$ terms.

Answer (score 1):

$f(v)$ is a probability density, so it is convenient to set

$$\int_0^{2V{_0}} \mathrm{d}v \, f(v) = 1$$

In your case this will give you an expression for $A$ in terms of $V_0$. Now, e.g.

$$\int_{V_0}^{2V{_0}} \mathrm{d}v \, f(v)$$

is the probability that a particle has velocity between $V_0$ and $2V_0$.

The average value of any function of $v$ can then be calculated as

$$\langle g\rangle = \int_0^{2V{_0}} \mathrm{d}v \, g(v)\, f(v)$$

Similarly the rms value can be calculated as

$$g_{rms} = \sqrt{\langle g^2 \rangle} = \int_0^{2V{_0}} \mathrm{d}v \, g^2\, f(v)$$

Hope that provides enough of a hint as to how to get the mean and rms velocity.

Answer (score 0):

$N$ is equal to the sum of the two integrals you have:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
N = \int_0^{2 V_0} dv \ f\left(v\right) &=& \int_0^{V_0} dv \ A + \int_{V_0}^{2 V_0} dv \left(-\frac{A}{V_0} v  + 2 A\right) \\
&=& A V_0 + \left[ -\frac{A}{2 V_0} v^2  + 2 A V\right]_{V_0}^{2 V_0} \\
&=& \frac{3}{2} A V_0  \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$